# Problem in the function of my program code python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to make a program to do the below things but apparently, the function doesn't work. I want my function to take two or more arguments and give me the average and median and the maximum number of those arguments.
example input:

```
calc([2, 20])
```

example output : `(11.0, 11.0, 20)`

```
def calc():
    total = 0
    calc = sorted(calc)
    for x in range(len(calc)):
        total += int(calc[x])
    average = total / len(calc)
    sorted(calc)
    maximum = calc[len(calc) - 1]
    if len(calc) % 2 != 0:
        median = calc[(len(calc) // 2) + 1]
    else:
        median = (float(calc[(len(calc) // 2) - 1]) + float(calc[(len(calc) // 2)])) / 2
    return (average, median, maximum)
```

Comment: You are handing arguments to your function but your function doesn't accept any arguments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing arguments into a function that doesn't accept any, you are getting an error. You could fix this just by making the first line of your program:

```
def calc(calc):
```

But it would be better to accept inputs into your function as something like "mylist". To do so you would just have to change your function like so:

```
def calc(mylist):
    calc=sorted(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some things I'm going to fix as I go since I can't help myself.

First, you main problem is arguments.
If you hand a function arguments

```
calc([2, 20])
```

It needs to accept arguments.

```
def calc(some_argument):
```

This will fix your main problem but another thing is you shouldn't have identical names for your variables.
`calc` is your function name so it should not also be the name of your `list` within your function.

```
# changed the arg name to lst
def calc(lst):  
    lst = sorted(lst)
    # I'm going to just set these as variables since
    # you're doing the calculations more than once
    # it adds a lot of noise to your lines
    size = len(lst)
    mid = size // 2

    total = 0
    # in python we can just iterate over a list directly
    # without indexing into it
    # and python will unpack the variable into x
    for x in lst:
        total += int(x)
    average = total / size
    
    # we can get the last element in a list like so
    maximum = lst[-1]
    if size % 2 != 0:
        # this was a logical error
        # the actual element you want is mid
        # since indexes start at 0
        median = lst[mid]
    else:
        # here there is no reason to explicity cast to float
        # since python division does that automatically
        median = (lst[mid - 1] + lst[mid]) / 2
    return (average, median, maximum)

print(calc([11.0, 11.0, 20]))
```

Output:

```
(14.0, 11.0, 20)
```